# call a method of one class from a different class c++

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, methods, instance

I asked this question earlier

[Create instance of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882002/create-instace-of-class)

```
fGCBS f1;
```

but when i try call it i get this error

```
error C2512: 'fGCBS' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Add parameterless constructor (i.e. default constructor as the message states).

Comment: Have you read and understood the error message?

Comment: You need to buy a book - even a stupid book like learn C++ in 10  minutes or something would cover this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

your class FGCBS has a constructor that looks like this

`fGCBS(AbstRaven_Bot* owner);`

Once you define a constructor that is not a default constructor the complier will no longer generate a default one for you.

To instantiate your class you need something like

`FGCBS foo(nullptr);`

or you need to add a default constructor

```
class FGCBS
{
public:
     FGCBS()
     {...}
};
```